# Will a GFCI device work on circuit where the neutral is switched?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

How well will a GFCI circuit be able to detect current flows, if both the "hot" input and the (supposedly) "neutral" input to a GFCI outlet are energized?

The reason I am interested in this is that I am renting an old (1915) townhome and have discovered that an (ungrounded) wall outlet and a ceiling fixture are both controlled by a wall switch that opens the netural wire instead of the hot wire.  The result is that when switch is off, the direct neutral line is open, but the netrual input of the GFCI is connected to hot.  When I reported this to the landlord, their electrical contractor put in a GFCI, but they do not want to correct the open neutral.  (I think it may be a knob and tube circuit with only the neutral line going through the wall switch, so fixing it may require pulling apart the wall and/or rerunning the entire circuit.)

For what it is worth, when the switch is off (and both inputs are energized), the GFCI test button will trigger a disconnect, but the  reset button is not functional.  But I'm not sure if the test button guarantees that the GFCI is providing effective protection in this scenario, hence my question: will a GFCI circuit work when both inputs are energized and it has no real neutral and no ground?

Comment: It isn't real clear from your question: Is the outlet (which is where the GFCI is presumably installed) switched or unswitched?

Comment: Both the outlet and the light fixture are downstream from and get turned "off" by the switch opening neutral.

Comment: And yes, the GFCI is integrated with the outlet receptacle.

Comment: If the junction box housing the switch receives both the hot and neutral, from upstream, it should be easy to fix. It should; I think it is against code (USA, Canada) for the two conductors of the same circuit to go through different routes in the walls. E.g. a just a neutral going to a switch and then toward the appliances, with the hot taking some other path that is nowhere near the switch.

Comment: @Kaz: I'm pretty certain the US codes explicitly allow for a hot/neutral pair to go to a light fixture, and for unswitched and switched hot to proceed from there to a junction box without a neutral tagging along.  It's interesting to note that in that case, even though both wires going to the switch are on the hot side, the current through them should be equal and opposite.

Comment: @Kaz: There are no "junction boxes" in K&T wiring. And yes, it's perfectly *legal* to leave such wiring in place as long as it's undisturbed. However, if any work needs to be done on the circuit, it does need to be brought up to code at that time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A GFCI is only measuring currents and does not care about the voltages on either of the two wires going through it.

As long as the net current is always zero, it really doesn't matter how it is switched on and off.

The real problem with a "switched neutral" is that the contacts inside the fixture are live with respect to ground even when the switch is off. If you should accidentally touch the contacts while grounded, the GFCI *will* protect you by tripping. But if the fixture were wired correctly, that particular risk wouldn't exist at all.

Comment: Thanks for the warning.  I actually don't think the GFCI was wired to put the light fixture downstream, so I think it is still unprotected.

Comment: For a GFCI to provide protection, the line neutral wire must be connected any time the line hot side is connected.  Disconnecting just the neutral side is very dangerous, since even in the presence of lethal fault currents the GFCI would have insufficient power to operate the solenoid to disconnect the mains.

Comment: @supercat: Yes, I was concerned about that too, but the OP states that the "test" button does trip the device even when the switch is off. I'm not really sure how that's working...

Comment: I just tried the test button again with the switch off (i.e., neutral open) and the test button does indeed trip the GFCI.

Comment: @Jeff: If the light isn't downstream and there's no load plugged into the GFCI, then the test resistor might pass enough current to trip the solenoid.  What happens if you plug in a low-resistance load like a 100W light fixture and have the fixture's switch turned on but the wall switch off?

Comment: I wonder if the GFCI has a capacitor that keeps the test GFCI circuitry running for some amount of time after the switch is turned off? Perhaps if it is kept off for a long amount of time (overnight?), the test button won't work? Otherwise, I don't see how the GFCI could get enough power to operate the tripping mechanism since it only has no voltage differential going to it (only the hot since the neutral and ground are open) or two (the hot and neutral are at ~120 V with an open ground).

Comment: @supercat I plugged a fixture with a 60W incandescent bulb and another with a 42W CFL bulb.  There was no change in behavior: the test button still trips regardless of the position of the switch and the reset button still only works when switch is on.

Comment: I've left this answer as accepted for now, because I think it is the best answer to the narrow question as to whether the GFCI can detect faults when both the hot and neutral line terminals are energized.  But I do still have concerns about whether it is able to reliably disconnect the circuit when a fault occurs.  The fact that the test button works suggests to me that it probably does, but I'd feel better if I understood how it was working.  For now I've been just been using the test functionality to deactivate the receptacle.

Comment: @Pigrew I'll try to run your experiment tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Jeff: I'm curious what you mean about the "reset button".  On the GFCI devices I'm familiar with the reset button mechanically resets the GFCI.  Does your GFCI indicate a tripped condition by having reset pop out or via some other means?  And when the reset "doesn't work", are you saying it doesn't stay latched on?

Comment: @Pigrew Leaving the neutral open overnight didn't change anything.  The test button still disconnects the circuit.

Comment: @supercat When I push the test button, the reset button physically pops out and disconnects the receptacle.  After this has occurred, if I leave the neutral energized, I can press in the reset button but it won't latch and the receptacle remains disconnected from the line terminals.  My understanding is that newer GFCI (manufactured after 2006) come "pre-tripped" and cannot be reset unless wired "correctly" (not having the line attached to the load terminals) and they pass some kind of self-test.  I'm not 100% sure, but from the outside my GFCI looks like a Leviton SmartLockPro.

Comment: BTW, I contacted Leviton, and their engineer confirmed that their GFCI's will provide protection in the my situation.

Answer (score 1):

**The situation you describe is dangerous and should be totally unacceptable.**

A GFCI whose hot can be connected to mains hot without the neutral connection being connected to mains neutral cannot be relied upon to provide any protection.  Suppose that a switched-off light bulb represents a 10-ohm resistance between the GFCI's load hot and load neutral terminals.  Suppose further that a 450-ohm path develops between the base of that bulb and ground while the GFCI neutral is switched off.  What's going to happen?

The GFCI hot terminals are going to be at mains potential, and the neutral terminals are going to be at about 98% of mains potential.  Even with 250mA flowing through the fault path, the potential difference between the GFCI hot and neutral terminals will only be about 2.5 volts.  Consequently, it's entirely possible that the GFCI won't trip even with a fault current that's well above a level generally regarded as lethal.

Comment: In the scenario you are describing, you say that the GFCI would not detect the current flowing out, because the currents on the load hot and load neutral terminals are similar, but Dave Tweed suggests that a GFCI detects "net current" flows.  In your scenario, both flows go out from the GFCI through the bulb to ground.  Can a GFCI not detect this?

Comment: GFIs trigger on any current imbalance over 6 mA, often 4 to 5.  (0.004 Amps) See [1](http://www.fluke.com/fluke/usen/community/fluke-news-plus/articlecategories/grounding/chasing-ghost-trips.htm) and [2](http://www.safeelectricity.org/information-center/library-of-articles/55-home-safety/317-ground-fault-circuit-interrupters-gfcis)

Comment: @jeff: A typical GFCI includes a relatively sensitive sensing circuit which, when a current imbalances is detected, feeds mains power into a solenoid which then opens the contact.  In the scenario I described, the sensing circuit would have no trouble "detecting" 250mA, but would be unable to open the contact in response.

Comment: @supercat I see what you are saying.  I had thought you were saying that the 2.5V difference wouldn't be enough for the detector circuit, but you are saying the 2.5V difference wouldn't allow the GFCI to draw enough power from the mains to physically open the contact.  I share that concern, but I'm having trouble imaging how the test button is working unless the GFCI device is designed to store sufficient potential energy operate the disconnect.